# ios - Efficiently iterate subviews and return a filtered UIView subset

Tags: ios, css, swift, mobile, css-selectors

Trying to implement a "css selector" traversal approach on swift.

I have the following implemented:

```
var CLASSNAME_HANDLE: UInt8 = 0
extension UIView {
    @IBInspectable var className: String {
        get {
            var optionalObject:AnyObject? = objc_getAssociatedObject(self, &CLASSNAME_HANDLE)

            if let object:AnyObject = optionalObject {
                return object as! String
            } else {
                return "" // default value when uninitialized
            }
        }
        set {
            objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &CLASSNAME_HANDLE, newValue, objc_AssociationPolicy(OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC))
        }
    }

    func getViewsByClass(cls: String) -> Array<UIView>{
        return selectViews({
            var classFound = false
            split($0.className){separator in
                separator == " "}.forEach({ className in
                    classFound = classFound || className == cls
                })
            return classFound
        })
    }

    func selectViews(filter:(UIView) -> Bool) -> Array<UIView>{
        var views = Array<UIView>()

        for view in self.subviews{
            if view.subviews.count > 0{
                views.extend((view as! UIView).selectViews(filter))
            }

        }

        views.extend(self.subviews.filter({ return filter($0 as! UIView) }) as! [UIView])
        return views
    }

}

extension Array {
    func forEach(doThis: (element: T) -> Void) {
        for e in self {
            doThis(element: e)
        }
    }
}
```

This allows me to add a className property in the interface builder, like so:
[image]

All is working as expected, however performance could be better.

**Q: How can I optimize this code?, or is there a better approach to iterate the subviews and return a filtered subset.**

Any advice is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is as fast as it gets in most cases. If you want this to perform better you'll need to pre-compute the result. IE each UIView should have a Dictionary with the class name as the key and an Array of UIViews which are its descendants bearing that class name.

This can be done using UIView notifications whenever it adds or removes a subview. You'll need to chain this upwards all the way to the top most superview. This way you can speed up retrievals at the cost of more expensive inserts and removals.

But doing this on UIView itself might involve swizzling and .

You might be able to avoid swizzling by storing a giant global dictionary for all the UIViews in the system outside any given UIView.

This is a bit of a hare brained scheme and I'm not suggesting that you do this , just sharing an approach on how this computation could be speeded up.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's strange that there is no native way to get multiple views with common attributes...

Comment: There is viewWithTag though. You might be able to do something by abusing it but again yet another hare brained idea :D .

Comment: alas the viewWithTag is unique and can't be used on multiple views, that is why I've added the className property